# Global pointer to local pointer array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have an array of pointers to arrays, in a function. I need to access that array in another function.

Pointer array

```
char *ptr[size + 1];
```

I made a global pointer

```
char *p;
```

which i pointed to ptr  (in the same function as ptr)

```
p = *ptr;
```

then i tried to access ptr from the other function

```
void otherFunction(void){
    for(int n = 0; n < 6; n++)
    {
        char* str = &p[n];
        printf("%i %s\n", n, str);
    }
}
```

when

```
ptr[0] = "abcd"
ptr[1] = "bcde"
ptr[2] = "cdef"
ptr[3] = "defg"
ptr[4] = "efgh"
ptr[5] = "fghi"
```

the output of `otherfunction();` is:

```
0 abcd
1 bcd
2 cd
3 d
4 
5
```

I want the output to be

```
 0 abcd
 1 bcde
 2 cdef
 3 defg
 4 efgh
 5 fghi
```

My questions are: (0) whats going wrong here. (1) How do i fix it (2) Or is there a better way to do this.  the requirements are `otherfunction()` cant take any arguments and `ptr` needs to remain local to its function. (Im certain the other code is not contributing to the problem and nothing is wrong with `ptr`)

Comment: `p = *ptr;` dereferences `ptr` and is identical to saying `p = ptr[0];`

Comment: you likely mean `p = ptr;`

Comment: You need to show more code.  Is the array of pointers static or automatic?  Is the function you show called from within the function or after the function has returned?  Please create an MCVE ([MCVE]) — it needn't be very much more code, but that will provide critical context that will allow intelligent and helpful answers.

Comment: You know you can pass parameters, don't you?

Comment: it should be noted that global pointers are rarely a good idea, especially if you're going to point them to local variables. Once the function completes, the stack will be cleaned up and you then get undefined behavior.

Comment: @Goodies and that's just a simple scenario where this would be a bad idea, global pointers are bad almost for any situation. Besides, there is always a solution other than using global variables and they are always better solutions than using global variables, so I recommend to avoid global variables as much as possible even if it sounds too drastic. Of course this comment is mostly for the OP.

Comment: @Goodies `p = ptr;` would be an error

Comment: @M.M I know, I meant to edit it after I realized it, but it was past the 5 minute limitation.

Answer (score 3):

`ptr` is an array of pointer.

```
char **p = ptr;

char *str = p[n];
printf("%i %s\n", n, str);
```

Comment: What is the use of `p`? Why not simply do `char* str = ptr[n];`?

Comment: @Lundin I don't know, ask to the OP. Maybe `p` is global but not `ptr`. This answer is just a quick answer not exhaustive, I already upvote the two other because of that.

Comment: That's kind of the point though. The OP most likely shouldn't have their "global pointer" to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

> `char *ptr[size + 1];`
>
> `char* p = *ptr;`
>
> `char* str = &p[n];`

This makes p point to the first string of the `ptr` array of strings, and then `str` will iterate over that string character by character. I think that what you meant to do is this:

```
char** p = ptr; // p points to the first string of ptr
...
char* str = p[n]; // str points to the nth string of ptr
```

Apart of that, using global pointers is not a good idea. Possibly better is to pass `ptr` itself to the function `otherFunction`, which would have the protoype:

```
void otherFunction(char** p);
```

and you call it with `ptr`:

```
otherFunction(ptr);
```

Answer (score 1):

> (0) whats going wrong here. (1) How do i fix it (2) Or is there a better way to do this

(0) The whole program design. Using global variables like this - pointers in particular - is one form of spaghetti programming and should be avoided. You are creating tight couplings and dependencies between all kinds of unrelated parts in your program.

In general, the presence of pointer-to-pointers is usually an indication of poor design. Pointer-to-pointers have a few valid uses, for special cases such as returning a modified pointer through a function parameter. There is no apparent reason to use them in your case.

(1) By using a couple of type qualifiers and storage specifiers to reduce scope of those messy, global variables. Instead, access the pointer array through setter/getter functions.

(2) Yes, change the program to something like the code below:

```
static const char* ptr [] =
{
  "abcd",
  "bcde",
  "cdef",
  "defg",
  "efgh",
  "fghi",
  NULL
};

inline const char* get_str (size_t index)
{
  return ptr[index];
}

inline void set_str (size_t index, const char* str)
{
  ptr[index] = str;
}
```

Comment: "In general, the presence of pointer-to-pointers is usually an indication of poor design.", so `int main(int, char **);` is a poor design? This is really strict. I totally agree with all your answer except that. 3 stars programmers must be punished, I agree but, two starts? There are many cases where they are valid.

Comment: @Stargateur `char** argv` is strictly speaking not a valid form of main, but of course `char* argv[]` decays into a pointer-to-pointer, so they are equivalent. The presence of two stars means that you are doing something out of the ordinary, like returning a pointer to malloc:ed data through a parameter - which is perfectly fine. Using pointer-to-pointer in other situations is in my experience most often the result of programmer confusion. For example incorrectly using `char** ptr = malloc(n*sizeof(*ptr)),` to allocate a "2D array".

Comment: It would however be fine to use pointer-to-pointer when allocating an array of pointers dynamically - though it would be more correct to use an array pointer in that case. Pointer-to-pointers are perfectly fine if you actually know what you are doing.